# Cpp - EXC_BAD_ACCESS in recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

Ive written a recursive function which uses std::vector for temporary data containers. The problem is that the code throws errors of **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** after certain **recursive iterations**, which dont seem to be associated with the code since the exception travels around.

I can **produce an exception** if i put anything at the **place of the code printf("This is funny ... not")**, any code before that seems to be executing okay.

I suspect that my system has run out of memory but from the activity monitor I can see that ive used 6.5 / 8GB RAM so this cannot be the case?

What may be the case of this EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception?

```
void Terrain::CarvePath(int index){

    float endElevation = 0.0f;

    int actualRowSize = 25 + 1;

    int upperRow = index - actualRowSize;

    int bottomRow = index + actualRowSize;

    if(bottomRow + 1 > 25 * 25 || upperRow - 1 < 0){
        return;
    }

    std::vector<int> surroundingIndices;

    // Throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS. If removed throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS 
    // on the next line ( surroundingIndices.push_back() )
    printf("This is funny ... not");

    surroundingIndices.push_back(upperRow - 1);
    surroundingIndices.push_back(upperRow);
    surroundingIndices.push_back(upperRow + 1);
    surroundingIndices.push_back(index - 1);
    surroundingIndices.push_back(index + 1);
    surroundingIndices.push_back(bottomRow - 1);
    surroundingIndices.push_back(bottomRow);
    surroundingIndices.push_back(bottomRow + 1);



    if(lastVertex){
       std::remove(std::begin(surroundingIndices), 
       std::end(surroundingIndices), lastVertex);
    }

    std::vector<float> surroundingIndicesY;

    for (auto &&surroundingIndex : surroundingIndices) {
         surroundingIndicesY.push_back
         (vertices[surroundingIndex].position.y);
    }

    std::vector<float>::iterator it;

    it = std::min_element(surroundingIndicesY.begin(), 
    surroundingIndicesY.end());

    long vertexToDigIndexTemp = 
    std::distance(surroundingIndicesY.begin(), it);

    int vertexToDigIndex = surroundingIndices[vertexToDigIndexTemp];

    vertices[vertexToDigIndex].position.y -= 1.0f;

    lastVertex = vertexToDigIndex;

    if(vertices[index].position.y == endElevation) return;

    CarvePath(vertexToDigIndex);

}
```

Comment: " I can see that ive used 6.5 / 8GB RAM so this cannot be the case?"  Yes, it can if the allocator cannot allocate a sufficiently large _contiguous_ chunk.

Comment: Could be something undefined somewhere else – trivial output changes having that effect on behaviour is usually a sign of that. Start with using the debugger to figure out what you're trying to access when it happens, and how deep the recursion went.

Comment: @NeilButterworth This is when pushing an `int` into an empty vector though, and I think that would more likely throw `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: The code was executing 2472 times before breaking ... The problem was the condition if(vertices[index].position.y == endElevation) return; would never evaluate to true, therefore the recursion would loop infinitely

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like a typical stack overflow. Since your code is recursive, you might end up with a lot of return addresses on the stack, which can lead to your stack running out of space. Converting your code to a non-recursive version could solve the problem.

Comment: Indeed this was a stackoverflow produced by my carelessness in handling the end of a recursive function, changing the conditional exit of recursion solved the problem.